# scala project export files

Tags: scala

I have the below query

```
val CubeData = spark.sql (""" SELECT gender, department, count(bibno) AS count FROM borrowersTable, loansTable  WHERE borrowersTable.bid = loansTable.bid GROUP BY gender,department WITH CUBE ORDER BY gender,department """)
```

And i want to export 4 files with specific data and names.

File1 consist of gender and departments and the name of file is geneder_departments
File2 gender,null name of file is gender_null
File3 departments,null name of file is departments_null
File4 null,null name of file is null_null
theses files are results from sql query (with cube)

i try the below

```
val df1 = CubeData.withColumn("combination",concat(col("gender") ,lit(","), col("department")))
df1.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("combination").format("csv").option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").save("final")
```

but i took more than 4 files - combination of gender - departments. Also names of those files are random. Is it possible to choose the name of those files?

Comment: you should expose your problem first. any error ?

Comment: @Mariana please open another question, not editing and removing the previous question. This affects other users who want to know about your previous question.

Comment: sorry i try to open new one but i can't. It said that i couldn't open a new so soon :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's a bug in Spark, I don't see any problem in your query, but the query below seems to work. You don't need to specify table names if they are unique columns.

```
val CubeData = spark.sql ("""
SELECT gender, department, count(bibno) AS count
FROM borrowersTable
JOIN loansTable USING(bid)
GROUP BY gender, department WITH CUBE
ORDER BY gender, department
""")
```

But there seems to be some problems in your file parsing, try this instead:

```
val borrowersDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "|").option("header", "True").option("inferSchema", "True").load("BORROWERS.txt")
borrowersDF.createOrReplaceTempView("borrowersTable")
val loansDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "|").option("header", "True").option("inferSchema", "True").load("LOANS.txt")
loansDF.createOrReplaceTempView("loansTable")

val CubeData = spark.sql ("""
SELECT gender, department, count(bibno) AS count
FROM borrowersTable
JOIN loansTable USING(bid)
GROUP BY gender, department WITH CUBE
ORDER BY gender, department
""")
```